# imshow() error: Doesn't show edge image

Tags: matlab, edge-detection, imshow

what's wrong with the code below?

```
>> x = imread('D:\Database\vehicle\35\1.jpg');

>> x1 = rgb2gray(x);

>> x2 = edge(x1);

>> imshow(x2);
```

it gives this error:

> Error using ==> iptcheckinput Function IMAGEDISPLAYVALIDATEPARAMS
>   expected its first input, I, to be one of these types:
>
> double, single, uint8, uint16, uint32, int8, int16, int32, logical
>
> Instead its type was edge.

It does show the original and the gray image, but doesn't show the edge image. How can I show an image after edge detection?

Actually my edge function also doesn't work. When I type:

```
>> x2
Edge ""
```

The output is empty.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. The result of edge is a logical matrix which can be passed to `imshow`. Are you sure this is exactly your code and only your code?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the code. I've tried every possible way and seen many examples, but it still gives that error. Isn't the output of edge function an image?

Comment: It seems that you have a function on your path named `edge.m` that is overloading the built-in. Check this with `which('edge')`. Then you'll want to delete it and remember to not name functions the same as built-ins.

Comment: Put a breakpoint, enter into `edge(x1);`, and follow the returned class.

Comment: When I type `which('edge')` it shows the path: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\scheduling\@edge\edge.m` . Is it the right file?

Comment: It got fixed. The edge function was for a different toolbox. Thank you _Suever, _Rotem and _Sembei Norimaki.

Comment: Closing due to minor error.